# Querydsl - paging functionality

Tags: querydsl

It seems that in Jpa QueryDsl I can use paging like:

```
return new JPAQueryFactory(getEntityManager())
    .selectFrom(entity)
    .where(where_clause)
    .orderBy(order_by_clause)
    .offset(pageNumber * 20)
    .limit(20)
    .fetchResults();
```

Questions are:

- Is it optimal approach? Does fetchResults load only 20 elements from DB and make count query to get information about total number of entities which are in db?
- Or maybe there is some option like .page(2).limit(20)?

*Yes I know that Spring-Data has already Paging and interface for QueryDsl but because of the complicated "order by" clause which is not supported by Spring-Data I cannot use it :(*

Comment: I am using querydsl too and needed implement paging outside pageable and sorting repository. Adil Khalil's answer helped.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Too late here but someone may find it helpful.

> Is it optimal approach? Does fetchResults load only 20 elements from DB and make count query to get information about total number of entities which are in db?

Yes - it will issue 2 queries. One for count with the where clause and the other for fetching results. This is desired when you are interested in knowing the number of records which meets the criteria (where clause) along with fetching the data as per the page size and offset. With using .fetchResults(), you should use the following methods to get the total count and the rows returned as following.

```
QueryResults<Tuple> result = query.fetchResults();
int totalCount = result.getTotal();
List<Tuple> rows = result.getResults();
```

> Or maybe there is some option like .page(2).limit(20)?

Yes - if you only want to fetch the results for offset and page size, you should use

```
List<Tuple> rows = query.limit(20).offset(2*20).fetch();
```

fetch() method will only issue 1 query to fetch the results 'limited' by the page size and offset specified.

Comment: I used as `QueryResults<Tuple> result = query.limit(20).offset(2*20).fetchResults();` and looks to work fine.

Comment: Just for everyone to know: fetchResults() is deprecated (and fetchCount() as well) since the count query can not be guaranteed to be correct in all cases apparently. Apparently "Blaze persistence" is an alternative, but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: @Stephanie Blaze Persistence seems to have fixed the issues with `fetchCount()` if you use their BlazeJPAQuery implementation

Answer (score 18):

`Querydsl.applyPagination()` can also be used.

```
org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

Querydsl querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, (new PathBuilderFactory()).create(<EntityClass>.class));
JPQLQuery<?> query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);

//TODO: prepare your query here 

//Get the count
Long totalElements = query.fetchCount();

//Apply the pagination
List<?> result = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, query).fetch();

//return a paged response
return new PageImpl<>(result, pageable, totalElements);
```

Comment: While this does accomplish pagination, I just want to point out that `fetchCount()` does not necessarily return the correct count if you have a statement like this `SELECT DISTINCT (a, b, c)` where your B and/or C come from a different entity/table that may be part of a join statement.